# Непонятен ряд вопросов касаемо принципа работы Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

1. На сколько я понимаю аспект - это отдельный элемент контекста Spring (т.е не является бином, а является чем-то другим в контексте Spring)?
   Честно признаться полазил по контексту не нашел аспектов)
2. Через что создаются прокси-классы при использовании аннотации `@Transactional`, много искал, везде пишут вроде, что через аспекты, но в итоге в `BeanFactory` нашел `beanPostProcessors(InfastructureAdvisiorAutoProxyCreator)`, в котором в `ProxyType` фигурирует мой класс с аннотацией `@Transactional`.
3. В какой момент создаются аспекты при создании контекста Spring.
4. Как именно происходит маппинг HTTP-запроса в Spring MVC через `@RequestMapping` на метод?

   - Т.е допустим идет POST с формой авторизации и маппится в метод. Как? Чем? Он раскидает в нужные поля?
   - Допустим у нас есть метод, который должен обрабатывать POST запрос в который приходит форма или JSON. Как сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, в следующий раз задавайте отдельные несвязанные вопросы отдельными вопросами. У вас здесь три вопроса: про аспекты, про `@Transactional` и про `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать, спасибо.